# "401 Unauthorized : The audience is invalid" Error with Azure AAD for .Net Core APIs

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Azure AD by default generates Application URI in below format.

api://<<Client_Id>>

but When you change Application URI with "https://xyz.onmicrosoft.com/<<Client_Id>>" and the token generated using Auth Code Grant or Client Credential flow, if passed to API for Authorization, you will get below error.

WWW-Authenticate: **Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The audience 'https://xyz.onmicrosoft.com/<<Client_Id>>' is invalid"**

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, AppSettings should be added as mentioned below,

```
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "xyz.onmicrosoft.com",
    "TenantId": <<Tenant_Id>>,
    "ClientId": <<Client_Id>>,
    **"Audience": "https://xyz.onmicrosoft.com/<<Client_Id>>"**
  }
```

**Note:** If you are using default URI then Audience is not required but with custom Application URI, Audience needs to be added.

Comment: Which .net version are you using ? which library ?

Comment: .Net Core 3.1 but tried this with .Net 6 too.

Answer (score 0):

In my application config file I had to set Audience to Application ID URI (api://myapp.com) and when fetching a token in Insomnia resource had to be set TO the same Application ID URI